# Market link giving Error 404

Tags: android, google-play

Iam using all the below links on Mobile browser but they ar given "not found Error 404".

```
http://market.android.com/details?id=<appMarketUidString>

market://details?id=<appMarketUidString>

http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:<package name>

http://market.android.com/search?q=pub:"<Developer name>"
```

how to resolve this.

Comment: in android mobile we have android market app  directly.so why u try this through browser or try this below link   http://market.android.com/details?id=<package name>

Comment: Does the handset have the Android Market app installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links look correct, but when you go to open them on your phone, make sure to open them with the Market App, because the mobile browser (or any other browser for that matter) does not open them properly.

Comment: How to open these links with Market App?

Comment: When you use the phone and click a link like you have above, it will ask you if you want to open with a browser or the market app. use the market app.