# I just uploaded my first app to the Android Market, and I'm getting a 404 when I try to download it

Tags: android

Here's the link to download my app from the play store:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dgolder.BCDining

I'm getting a 404 when I try to install it and I'm not sure what could be causing it. I'll put my manifest in here too and I can provide any other info.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dgolder.BCDining"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="me.activity.DiningExpList"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            >            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="me.activity.DiningActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
         >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: How are you trying to isntall it? I've never seen a 404 error when trying to install an app through the android market? Also how long ago did you upload it?

Comment: Uploaded about 20 minutes ago, installing through market by clicking "Install" from PC if that makes sense.

Comment: The link is working just fine fella. No 404.

Comment: The 404 comes on the device when you try and install it. Did that work for you too? Sorry this is confusing.

Comment: Hmmm... it really is. And by device, you mean a tablet or would a mobile do too? Although, accessing the website for an app hardly makes sense. I would rather use the Google Play App?

Comment: So if you go to the link above, there is a button that says "Install" (or something like that). Clicking it will open Google Play on the device you select (in my case, my Galaxy Nexus) and attempt to download my app. Google play throws a 404. I have no idea why.

Comment: Clicking the link from my phone (as expected) prompts between the "Internet" and "Play Store" choices. The Play Store shows the app as it should. And so does the website actually.

Comment: Oh. Now it makes sense. Will give it a run on my tablet then.

Comment: Oh yeah. Now I get the error. And now it makes sense.

Comment: Sorry I was miserable at explaining it but it's just such a weird thing to be happening. The apk is definitely there...

Comment: The only link where the same problem was solved is this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1606850 But that is hardly a solution for your problem. Most of what I have been reading the last few minutes suggests that the problem is really in the Play Store app and is beyond a dev's control. I suppose, waiting it out seems a better options ATM. Oh, by the way, I don't see a problem in the Manifest.xml code you have attached.

Comment: Tried it one more time and the App installed. :-)

Comment: Thanks for looking. I just randomly tried again and it worked. Thanks for all of your time!

Comment: By the way, I might have submitted your first crash report for this app. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the links with your browser or with the market app? See this question: [Market link giving Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747885/market-link-giving-error-404)

Comment: I was installing through the market. Clicking the link I provided lets you install apps directly to your phone. The "404" comes from the market itself, which is the weird part.